# Swift - WKWebView is not opening links from websitesI

Tags: swift, wkwebview

I have the next policy in my `WKWebView`

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
        switch navigationAction.navigationType {
        case .linkActivated:
            decisionHandler(.allow)
            return
        default:
            break
        }
        decisionHandler(.allow)
    }
```

But, every time I try to open a link, I get:

```
BackgroundTask] Background Task 7 ("GDTCCTUploader-upload"), was created over 30 seconds ago. In applications running in the background, this creates a risk of termination. Remember to call UIApplication.endBackgroundTask(_:) for your task in a timely manner to avoid this

[Feedback] failed initializing core haptics engine for <_UIFeedbackCoreHapticsEngine: 0x283fc3aa0>: Error Domain=com.apple.CoreHaptics Code=-4810 "(null)"
```

I don't have anything special on my project, just the browser, but it is not allowing me to open  web sites likes.

Why is giving me that error and how can I solve it?

**UPDATE**

This happens when I search in `google` the word *cuevana* and try to open the link,

The other browser can open the site, but that site produces a lot of error, like this:

> Feedback] failed initializing core haptics engine for
> <_UIFeedbackCoreHapticsHapticsOnlyEngine: 0x282e49570>: Error
> Domain=com.apple.CoreHaptics Code=-4810 "(null)"

Comment: Are you using any cocoapods?

Comment: Just a pod `SwiftLinkPreview`

Comment: Is it the latest version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, I have to implement this;

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
        
        if navigationAction.navigationType == WKNavigationType.linkActivated {
            let url = navigationAction.request.url!.absoluteString
            
            let shared = UIApplication.shared
            webview.load(url)
            decisionHandler(WKNavigationActionPolicy.allow)
            return
            
        }

        decisionHandler(WKNavigationActionPolicy.allow)
    }
```